# onclick="location.href='<?php the_permalink() ?>';" open in new window

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick, target

I had to make the link of a div

```
<div onclick="location.href='<?php the_permalink() ?>';></div>
```

to make it work the way I needed it too. (Using Wordpress)

But I also need the link to open in a new window using target="_blank" but that I can't figure out how to apply that to an onclick in a div. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: do you really want div here. you can just use `<a href="link" target="_blank">..</a>` tag for this.

Answer (score 2):

You could always make a the onclick open up a javascript function and do what ever you need in there.

Or if you want that format

```
<div onclick="window.open('<?php the_permalink() ?>')"></div>
```

Comment: np, you can always accept the answer and vote up you know? :)

Comment: I need more reputation for that